# CodeIgniter: I would like to convert data add into array

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and MYSQL.

I have table1, which has one field (name).

In filed name it has values such as ABC,DDDD and EEE.

SQL statment:

```
value of field name
ABC
DDDD
EEE

Select name from table1
```

I want to convert data that i selected to formatted as the following.

```
Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => DDDD [2] => EEE )
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$q = $this->db->get('table1');
if ($q->num_rows() > 0):
   foreach($q->result() as $r):
       $data[] = $r->name;
   endforeach;
endif;
```

$data holds your array.